# JS: What are the args in a debounce function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grasp a debounce function in an existing codebase I am working on but I have a question that I can't understand while looking at it.  What is `(...args)` in this scenario?  I know it's a rest parameter but where did it come from and what is the purpose of `args` here?  Why can't that just be empty and then called like `fn()` in the setTimout?

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
    let id;
    return function(...args) {
        if (id) {
           clearTimeout(id)
        }
        id = setTimeout(() => {
           fn(...args);
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because sometimes you may want to call your debounced function with arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function being returned from debounce() is supposed to act exactly the same as the function being provided, except for the fact that we're limiting how often it gets called. This means that if the original function was supposed to take two parameters, the returned function should too. That's why spread is being used.

As a simpler example, lets consider a wrapper function that just adds 1 to whatever gets returned.

```
function alsoAdd1(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    return fn(...args) + 1
  }
}
```

To use it, we can do the following:

```
> multiplyAndAdd1 = alsoAdd1(function(x, y) { return x * y })
> multiplyAndAdd1(2, 3)
7
> doubleAndAdd1 = alsoAdd1(function(x) { return x * 2 })
> doubleAndAdd1(2)
5
```

Notice how it doesn't matter how many parameters we pass into the wrapped function (like doubleAndAdd1), they're all get passed along to the original function (the double function). This is because we're using the spread operator.

If we look at the definition of alsoAdd1, we see that it'll give back a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments, and passes all the arguments it receives into the function its wrapping.

The debounce() function is doing exactly the same thing, there's just a little bit more going on. These wrapper functions can be a little tricky to wrap your head around, so try going through those above examples slowly and see if you can grasp what they're doing.

Comment: @scotty...brilliantly explained, thanks so much

Comment: @scotty Thanks for your explanation. I can clearly see how the arguments are passed from your example, but I am also confused about how the pointer event is being passed when it is used within addEventListener like this: button.addEventListener("click", debounce((e) => console.log("clicked")));
Is this because the event is automatically passed to the anonymous function in debounce()?

Comment: @DPark - Yes, so addEventListener will call the function given to it with the event object. In this case, it'll call the function returned by debounce with the event object. That will be received in the spread arguments and passed along to the anonymous inner function. You just need to remember the function returned by debounce acts the same in every way as that inner function (because, it'll actually call the inner anonymouse function with the arguments it receives), the only difference is it'll delay some calls.

Comment: I appreciate the answer from @ScottyJamison . I was still struggling to understand how `...args` could be passed to the returned function if they weren't in fact included as a parameter of `debounce`.

As is articulated, the objective is to return a new function, behaving the same as `fn` with x arguments but executed after elapsed `delay`. So, the proper use is to assign the return to some variable and then invoke _that_ variable with x arguments. `...args` doesn't exist until invocation! In the examples, invoking `multiplyAndAdd1` and `doubleAndAdd1` demonstrates the need for `...args`.